# SceneKit – UV projection from Camera node

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, camera-projection

I am trying to project 360 image from camera to mesh [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_uZcrHn3rM&ab_channel=CIsnard).

If anyone has idea on how to do this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Unity, Autodesk Maya or The Foundry NUKE, in SceneKit a camera cannot be a projector. Even if the SCNCamera could be used as a 360-projector, it would require a rig of 6 cameras with a ***square far clipping plane*** for each camera ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769722/how-to-use-environment-map-in-arkit/50772728#50772728)), not a rectangular far clipping plane, like you're using.

### Solution 1 – Gobo

To create a 360-projector, use ***6 spot lights*** (with *north-south-east-west-up-down* directions) with `gobo` effect. Gobo is supposedly an acronym for "goes between optics".

Here's a sample code for a single spot (add each spot as a child node to your camera).

```
let projector = SCNNode()
projector.light = SCNLight()
projector.light?.type = .spot
projector.position.y = 10

projector.light?.gobo?.contents = UIImage(named: "imageForProjection.jpg")

projector.light?.gobo?.contentsTransform.m11 = 0.5    // texture's scale X
projector.light?.gobo?.contentsTransform.m22 = 0.5    // texture's scale Y

projector.light?.intensity = 1000
projector.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2
camera.addChildNode(projector)
```

[image]

Also, there are three useful properties to control light's attenuation:

```
var attenuationStartDistance: CGFloat { get set }
var attenuationEndDistance: CGFloat { get set }
var attenuationFalloffExponent: CGFloat { get set }
```

### Solution 2

Sometimes, you need a [Procedural Ambience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70523927/why-scnlight-created-automatically-in-scnscene-scenekit/70556347#70556347) and an [Environmental Lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739214/using-a-mtltexture-as-the-environment-map-of-a-scnscene/52202973#52202973) with a cubic image map.

### Solution 3

To generate a spherical, cubic or cylindrical projection from scratch, use [Apple Metal](https://metalbyexample.com).

Comment: I want to do 360 spherical projection from camera node. One problem i found  with light node is texture looks faded and doesnot looks good when projecting into mesh..