# How to add a gobo to a SpotLight in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, realitykit

I wanted to use gobo for a SpotLight in RealityKit. However, I could not find any documentation how to do that. I only found information about how to do it for SceneKit. But as SceneKit can not be used in combination with RealityKit, I could not find a way to do that.

Has anybody done this before, as I do not want to rewrite the whole app in SceneKit?

Answer (score 0):

### Gobo in RealityKit

Unfortunately, the current version of Apple RealityKit 2.0 does not allow a developer to add a [GOBO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626898/scenekit-uv-projection-from-camera-node/72633328#72633328) (a.k.a. stenciled light mask) to the [light source](https://medium.com/macoclock/realitykit-911-lighting-and-shadows-66f99bcd5219) (how you used to do in SceneKit). Below are the options that the SpotLight fixture currently has in RealityKit.

```
let spot = SpotLight()
spot.light.color
spot.light.intensity
spot.light.attenuationRadius
spot.light.innerAngleInDegrees
spot.light.outerAngleInDegrees
```

### Solution

The only way to add a gobo to your lighting scene is to use a fake texture or [fake shadows](https://medium.com/geekculture/realitykit-911-fake-shadows-for-stationary-models-78387aabf42c).